# What is the English word for this big pipe?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

In *Cellular (2004)* movie, There is a scene at the top of building construction, Ryan jumped into some big sliding pipe to escape from the Ethan.

[image: Person sliding inside a large tube]

Is there any English word for this big pipe ?

Comment: I think *chute* is what you are after. Perhaps *canvas debris chute* or *industrial chute*.

Comment: I call that stuff ventilator duct hose. It is used for temporary air handling in construction sites. [Link](https://ducting.com/collections/large-diameter-hose/products/air-ventilator-duct-hose-orange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK at least they're called "Rubbish chutes" or sometimes "Rubble chutes", eg

http://www.kingfisherdirect.co.uk/building-and-construction/rubbish-rubble-chutes

https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/112612153350?chn=ps&dispItem=1&adgroupid=46846106558&rlsatarget=pla-351087431970&abcId=1128966&adtype=pla&merchantid=113708795&poi=&googleloc=9041108&device=c&campaignid=857332737&crdt=0

[image]

With reference to "Escape chute" and "pipe slide", as mentioned in other answers:  I think the key difference between those and a rubble chute is that a rubble chute **is not designed for humans to slide down**, and in fact may be very dangerous, perhaps fatal, for them to do so (I certainly would not want to jump down the one in the above picture, for example, which would deposit you at very high speed into who-knows-what at the bottom).

I think this is what the OP is asking about, given the description of it being at the top of some building construction, but I haven't seen the film in question.

Comment: US, would be *trash and/or debris chute*,

Answer (score 0):

When used by a human being for amusement, that's a **pipe slide**.

Grace shooting out of the [**"Pipe Slide"**](https://br.pinterest.com/pin/127015651968424768/) at the Owen Farm Fall Festival

[image]

There is also a "rolling pipe slide" which has a slightly different mechanism. (see photo below)

[image]

Comment: The former type is also known as a *tube slide*, at least in British English, where *pipe slide* is very rare

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an [Escape Chute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_chute) to me:

> An escape chute is a special kind of emergency exit, used where conventional fire escape stairways are impractical. The chute is a fabric (or occasionally metal) tube installed near a special exit on an upper floor or roof of a building, or a tall structure. During use, the chute is deployed, and may be secured at the bottom by a fire fighting crew some distance out from the building. Once the tube is ready, escapees enter the tube and slide down to a lower level or the ground level.
>   <sub>*from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_chute)*</sub>

It may also be referred to as an "evacuation chute".